# Python: the len() function doesn't recognize 0 at the start

Tags: python, function

I want to test whether a 10 digit number is of 10 length, but whenever the number begins with 0, len() only counts 9.
How can I fix this?

At the moment:

something is a variable made up of numbers, I converted the variable into a string, then made this statement.

```
if len(something) != 10:
    (do something)
```

My current code:

```
number = int(input("Enter number: "))

number = str(number)

if len(number) != 10:
    print ("Not 10 digits long")
else: 
    print ("Good")
```

If I inputted a number with 10 digits it's fine, BUT, when I input a number with 10 digits and starting with zero, the len() function recognizes the number as 9 long. Help plz

Comment: show complete code which reproduces the problem.

Comment: what does it means when number start with `0` it counts 9. plz give ur desired input , wt u getting and expected output

Comment: in what form is the 10 digit number stored?

Comment: `len` does not such thing. `something` does not contain what you think it contains (probably the leading 0 is missing). To diagnose why, we need to see [more code](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Numbers don't start with a zero and don't have a length. You are confusing a number with a string representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing yout code, it's because you are casting your input to int, then casting it down to string (input automatic type is str in Python3, if you're using Python2, don't forget to cast as str or using raw_input like hackaholic).

Replace

```
number = int(input("Enter number: "))

number = str(number)
```

By

```
number = input("Enter number: ")
```

So number will directly be a string. And you can use len() on it. It even works with 0000000000

Comment: Thank you very much Robin Carlier for a swift and correct response <3

Comment: `input`'s type is string in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

you forcing it to integer, input take values as string

```
 number = input("Enter number: ")

if len(number) != 10:
    print ("Not 10 digits long")
else: 
    print ("Good")
```

`len` function works on string

if you using python 2.x better to use `raw_input("Enter Number: ")`

Answer (score 0):

Numbers starting with 0 are represented in base 8 (octal numbers) in python. You need to convert them to string to count their digits :

```
# Not converted
number1 = 0373451234
print "number: "+str(number1)+" digits:"+str(len(str(number1)))
```

**> number: 65950364 digits:8**

```
# Converted
number2 = "0373451234"
print "number: "+str(number2)+" digits:"+str(len(str(number2)))
```

**> number: 0373451234 digits:10**